# Doubly Linked List Double sorted and unsorted Add Method problem

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

So, I've searched all over for over a week and haven't been able to find a solution to my problem. My professor helped a bit but I just can't figure out how to add the nodes in sorted order.

What I'm supposed to do:

Write an add method that adds node to a list in unsorted order(as the user inputs them(hypothetically)) and in ascending order from least to greatest.

My issue: I can add the nodes in unsorted order however I don't understand why I can't create the unsorted one. I'm clearly missing something and in all the examples I've looked at none of them are doing what I'm supposed to be doing, and it's too hard to follow the ones that are only doing sorted order because they use all these classes/interfaces or whatever that I'm not supposed to use I think or that I don't understand how to use them.

The linked list nodes have a next, previous, nextSorted, previousSorted, and data.

```
public void add(T t) {
    Node node = new Node(t, null, null, null, null);
    tail.prev.next=node;
    node.next=tail;
    tail.prev=node;         

    if(size==0) {
        node.nextSort=tail;
        head.nextSort=node;
        node.prevSort=head;
        tail.prevSort=node;

    }else{
        Node curr = head.nextSort;
        while(curr!=null) {
        if(t.compareTo(curr.data)<0) {
            node.nextSort=curr;
            curr.prevSort.nextSort=node;
            node.prevSort=curr.prevSort;
            curr.prevSort=node;
        }

    }
    size++;
}
```

This is my add method, the first few lines work as expected but the rest, I don't really know what to do with the rest. I'm very confused at this point and very frustrated as nothing seems to be working.

```
/**
* This is the doubly-linked list node.
*/
private class Node
{
        private T data;
        private Node prev;
        private Node next;
        private Node prevSort;
        private Node nextSort;

        /**
         * Constructs basic list node.
         *
         * @param d The data element held by the list node.
         * @param p A Node that occurs immediately before this in list order.
         * @param n A node that occurs immediately after this in list order.
         */
        private Node(T d, Node p, Node n, Node ps, Node ns)
        {
            data = d;
            prev = p;
            next = n;
            prevSort = ps;
            nextSort = ns;
        }
}
```

This is the node class.

I'm just looking for a clue on what I might be doing wrong, like, if my connections are messed up or not when it comes to sorted or if I'm doing something weird. Even a link with simple explanations would be helpful as I'm not good with vocabulary/jargon.

Comment: Too much linking!  First _search_ (just search) down the sorted list until you find the spot where you want to insert  your new node, _then_ link it in.  Also be sure you are correctly handling the cases where the new node should go in before the current head or after the current  tail.

Comment: I don't understand your question, you mean you have to make 2 ```add``` methods? One that adds a node in a sorted order and one that adds a node in an unsorted order?